# How to show list content in Twig Drupal 8 without views

Tags: twig, themes, drupal-8

Sorry, I'm newbie in Drupal 8.
Is there any ways if we want to show content using Twig template in Drupal 8.
I have 2 kind of content let's say:

1. Article Content
2. Slider Content

I want to show them in front of my Drupal 8 page.
I see another suggestion is using views, but can I show them via Twig template?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to create your own controller or custom plugin block to loads pages that you want and prints it in twig. Or you have to prepare your nodes variable using hook_preprocess_hook and then it will be able using twig.
[doc @here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x)